# Is there a way to select polygons by geometry (right angle)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometry, arcgis-10.3, select, qgis-2.10

Is there a way to select polygons by geometry?

I need to find a way to detect all the polygons that have a right angle, but I can't find a tool that can do that.

I'm using QGIS 2.10.1 and ArcGIS for desktop 10.3.
I'm open to any other free software.

Comment: you need to calculate the angle of your geometry features first 
Calculate Grid Convergence Angle (Cartography)  will do this (Advanced License required) GEOGRAPHIC|ARITHMETIC|GRAPHIC needs defining http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/Calculate_Grid_Convergence_Angle/00700000000n000000/

Comment: Not sure I understand.This tool calculates the rotation angle for true north, right? How will I then be able to identify the polygons that have a right angle?

Comment: The workflow could be: Explode polygon to segments,  compute azimuth of each segment, compare azimuths of subsequent segments. I do not know yet how to do it exactly but probably it will not be very difficult.

Comment: As it stands I think your question is too broad because you have not focussed it on the GIS software that you wish to investigate first.  I think you should [edit] you question to say what you are using, and how far you have got with trying to answer your own question prior to posting.